# How to get just the user name of administrator using batch script in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, admin, runas

I want to use "runas /user:admin_name "cmd.exe ....." in my batch script.
I need a way to find out precisely the username of the administrator, so that it can be used in "/user:admin_name".
If I run "net localgroup administrators", I do get the name of the administrator, but it seems like I have to dig it out from a load of strings as shown in the output below. And  this script will be runnning on many different machines which I don't have access to. So, I don't know how exactly the output of "net localgroup administrators" will look like on all the machine configurations. How can I get the name of local administrator without any ambiguity on all Windows machines running NT or Vista or Win-7 ot Win-8 on the network or off the network ?

Alias name     administrators
Comment        Administrators have complete and unrestricted access to the computer/domain

Members

---

Administrator
PETERPAN
The command completed successfully.

Comment: There can be more than one name in the local administrators group (where I work we have several). How exactly would you like to handle that situation?

Comment: I want any one admin's username in this specific case. I don't really care who that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "admins="
SET "prev="
FOR /f "delims=" %%A IN ('net localgroup administrators') DO (
 CALL SET "admins=%%admins%% %%prev%%"
 SET "prev=%%A"
)
SET admins=%admins:*- =%
ECHO admins are "%admins%"
GOTO :EOF
```

This should get you a list of administrators from `net localgroup administrators`

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm a bit new to batch scripts. Took a while to understand CALL SET which seems to be an advanced feature. Will be quite useful in future too.